# Solving $-7\leq\sqrt{x}\leq5$ by squaring on both sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$-7\leq\sqrt{x}\leq5$
On squaring both sides we get the correct answer as:
$0\leq{x}\leq25$.

Why not $25\leq{x}\leq49$?
Why lower limit is taken as zero?

Comment: A square root can't be negative

Comment: $-3\leq{x}\leq5$ then range of x^2 will be in this case? $9\leq{x^2}\leq25$ or $0\leq{x^2}\leq25$? Asking this for my understanding @Matheman Please, help me. I will be really grateful

Comment: Hey, @FarrukhAtaev, can you help me out with the above comment. I am really sorry guys, I can't wait for 20 minutes because I am stuck at it for half an hour and I have an exam tomorrow

Comment: your example is related to the function $y=x^2$ that is the inverse of $y=\sqrt(x)$ so it isn't pertinent. The argument of all even indexed roots has to be positive.

Comment: I did not get what you said @Matheman, please can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @onlymaths Don't ask exam questions here. You have asked a lot already, and if you just want an answer only for some exams, this site is not the right place for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because: $$-7\leq\sqrt{x}\leq5 \iff 0\leq\sqrt{x}\leq5.$$

Comment: Didn't understand @FarrukhAtaev

Comment: by definition $\sqrt{x}\ge 0$, so the two inequalities are equivalent

Comment: even if you had $\sqrt{x}\le5$, by squaring you will get $0\le x\le 25$, because the function $y=\sqrt{x}$ has the domain $x\in [0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

To clear your confusion, try to divide the inequality to two inequalities:
$$-a\leq\ x \leq b \iff -a\leq x \leq 0 \ \lor \ 0\leq x \leq a$$
then
$$-a\leq\ x \leq b \iff 0\leq-x \leq a \ \lor \ 0\leq x \leq a$$
after evaluate the two inequalities, make sure to merge the results.

In your case, there is, in addition to the two inequalities, a third inequality :
$$-7\leq\sqrt{x}\leq5 \iff -7\leq\color{#f00}{\sqrt{x}\leq0} \ \lor \ 0\leq\sqrt{x}\leq5 \  \land \ \color{#f00}{\sqrt{x}\geq0}$$
so, we omit $ \ -7\leq\sqrt{x}\leq0 \ $, and the results are:  $\ x\in [0,25] \ \land \ x\in [0,+\infty[ $

Answer (score 0):

$-7 \le \sqrt{x} \le 5$

$\sqrt{x}$ refers to the principal square root and it cannot be negative. so the above expression is equal to

$0 \le \sqrt{x} \le 5$ which on squaring gives $0 \le x \le 25$